# Trouble with .Resize and UBound functions (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba, excel, normalize

I'm completely new to Visual Basic and am trying to create a macro that will take my Excel sheet and will normalize it. Here is a sample of my data:

[The full data spans around 200 columns and nearly 50,000 rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Sbm.png)

This is how I would like my data to look in the end:

[Normalized data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A94PI.png)

I found some code online to do this, but one of the lines has an error and I can't figure out what's wrong. Here is the code:

```
Sub TransposeRows()
Dim vIn, i As Long, j As Long, vOut, lngCnt As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, vFirstRow
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lngLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
vFirstRow = Range("A2", Cells(1, lngLastCol)).Value
vIn = Range("A2", Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastCol)).Value
ReDim vOut(1 To (lngLastCol - 1) * UBound(vIn, 1), 1 To 3)
For i = 1 To UBound(vIn, 1)
    For j = 2 To lngLastCol
        lngCnt = lngCnt + 1
        vOut(lngCnt, 1) = vIn(i, 1)
        vOut(lngCnt, 2) = vFirstRow(1, j)
        vOut(lngCnt, 3) = vIn(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
With Worksheets.Add
    .Range("A1:C1").Value = Array("ID", "AmtID", "Value")
    .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), 3).Value = vOut
End With
End Sub
```

Excel tells me the problem is in the third from the bottom .Range line, and I believe specifically something is wrong with the .Resize function and the UBound function. When I run it as is Excel tells me that there is a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

This code I found was from 2008, so some time has passed. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try taking out the leading `.`. I don't think you can do `Worksheet.Add.Range().Resize.Value = x` in one go. I think just `Range().Resize().Value = x` is what you want.

Comment: @BruceWayne, you can definitely use the `With` code as written.  A quick test will confirm it.  The `With ... Add` stores a reference to the new `Worksheet` which is then used twice to call `Worksheet.Range` essentially.

Comment: If you run the debugger and watch the contents of `vOut` at that line, what is there?  Also, you should probably split that line up so that you can spot the problem.  Right now you have 3 possible sources of error: the call to `UBound`, the call to `Resize`, the call to `Value` using `vOut` as the new contents.  You should store the value of `UBound` and possibly store a reference resulting from `Resize`.  With all those variables you can pinpoint the problem and then resolve it.  It's impossible to tell from here.